# Java - Reading Objects from a text file

Tags: java, file, text, io

I have a program in Java with several classes, these being:

i) Shape
ii) Square
iii) Rectangle
iv) Circle
v) Triangle
vi) Drawing Canvas
vii) Application

Square, Rectangle, Circle and Triangle all inherit from class **Shape**

Now, in the **Drawing Canvas** class, I have two methods, one for writing objects of type Shape to a file and one for reading objects from the file.

This is the code:

The method which saves to the file works perfectly.  However, I am having a problem reading the objects from the file and appending them to the Shapes ArrayList.

As it is, the application is given me the error that **java.lang.String cannot be cast to shapes_assignment.Shape**.

How can I read the text stored in the text file and use it to recreate the objects once more?  Thanks :)

Comment: What line is the error caused by?

Comment: It is caused by this line:

Shapes.add((Shape)temp.get(i));

Comment: is shapes an ArrayList<Shape> ??

Comment: Yes.  Shapes is an arraylist of type Shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a reader that will take the input string, and make a shape out of it. Here is a simple example to show you how this can work, using the [Java Date class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Not having your Shape constructors, I can't write your Shape for you.

```
Date today=new Date();
long var_to_write=today.getTime();

//Save this in to a file, then read it out as long var_in_file

Date previousTime=new Date(var_in_file);
```

Comment: The constructor for the shapes is Shape(int x, int y)

Comment: I just had an idea.  I will only save the type of shape and the co-ordinates in the text file, and then use them to recreate the shapes.  Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you are adding a String into your ArrayList.

```
            while(input.hasNext())
            {
                temp.add(input.next());
            }

            Shapes.add((Shape)temp.get(i));
```

here you are trying to **cast** a **String**(temp.get(i) will return a String) to **Shape type**, which is leading to **ClassCaseException**.

create a Shape instance after you read from the file and populate your ArrayList (temp) with Shape instances.

```
      List<Shape> temp = new ArrayList<Shape>();
      //read from the scanner and make an Shape object. 
       Shape shape = new Shape(your arguments to the Shape cons);
       now, while adding into shapes you wont need a case, as you made yourself sure that your ArrayList would only accept Shape

       shapes(temp.get(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `ObjectOutputStream` to write the list of shapes, and retreave them from an `ObjectInputStream`:

```
out.writeObject(Shapes);

Shapes = (ArrayList)in.readObject();
```

assuming `Shapes` is an `ArrayList`.